# Delete whole Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to **C** and I'm wondering if it is possible to delete a whole array, not just an element, in **C**?
In C++ there is the `delete[]`, is there something similar in **C**?

Comment: My intention was to delete the array so that i could re-use the name. I.e. reload the array with data from another file when switching level in a game. Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 10):

1) If the declartion of your array was done in this way:

```
int A[20];
```

Your array could not be deleted because it's allocated statically

2) If the declartion of your array was done in this way:

```
int *A=malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
//or
int *A=calloc(20, sizeof(int));
```

Your array could be deleted with `free(A)` because it's allocated dynamically

Answer (score 7):

You can just use `free` to delete a dynamically allocated array.

```
int* array = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
...
free(array);
```

If you allocated memory for each array element, you'll also need to `free` each element first.

```
char** array = malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(i);
}
....
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate memory in C using `malloc`, some extra information is stored after (or before) the allocated chunk. `free` uses this information to know how much memory you allocated in the first place and will free the entire chunk. 
So if you allocated only a single element, for example a struct, it will only free one element. If you allocated an entire array of struct, it will free the entire thing.

In C++, you use `new` and `new []` instead of malloc, which initializes values using constructor. Which is why there are two distinct `delete`: one for single value (`delete`), and one for arrays (`delete []`).

Answer (score 1):

If you've allocated the array dynamically (with `malloc()`), you just use `free()` to de-allocate it. Then you can no longer access the pointer, since you no longer "own" the memory.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you don't call `delete` unless you've used `new`. If you didn't use dynamic allocation, you don't free the memory.

In C, have a look at `malloc` and `free` if you want to control the lifetime of your arrays.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *array = malloc (size_in_bytes);

/* Some stuff. */

free (array); /* When I don't need it anymore. */
```

Otherwise, automatic variables are automatically released.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `malloc()`/`calloc` simply use `free()`:

```
type * ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(type));
if(ptr == NULL)
    couldnt_allocate_memory();
/* ... */
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creation of the tab : malloc or calloc functions. And then free function to deallocate it

Answer (score 0):

In C, if you are declaring your array as static
ex: int a[10], no need to delete. It will be freed when your function ends or program terminates. If you have allocated memory using any of memory allocation techniques[malloc,calloc], since it is allocated by you, should be freed by yourself and you use free(ptr) for freeing allocated memory block.